# Compare two objects using Chai assertions

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have two arrays of mixed orders

```js
const actualResult = [
  {
    start: '30',
    end: '50',
    locations: ['loc1', 'loc2'],
  },
  {
    start: '20',
    end: '40',
    locations: ['loc3', 'loc4'],
  },
];

const expectedResult = [
  {
    start: '20',
    end: '40',
    locations: ['loc4', 'loc3'],
  },
  {
    start: '30',
    end: '50',
    locations: ['loc2', 'loc1'],
  },
];
```

I have written the below code to compare them using chai assertions

```js
describe('test1', function () {
  it('expect test', function () {
    expect(actualResult).to.have.length(expectedResult.length);
    for (b of expectedResult) {
      var found = false;
      for (d of actualResult) {
        if (b.start == d.start && b.end == d.end) {
          expect(b.locations).to.have.deep.members(d.locations);
          found = true;
        }
      }
      expect(found).to.be.true;
    }
  });
});
```

which works fine but I'm interested to know if there are any direct chai assertions that I can perform in one line like

```
expect(actualResult).to.have.all.nested.members(expectedResult);
```

or better suggestions.

Comment: https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep

Comment: You can also create your own helpers: https://www.chaijs.com/guide/helpers/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [deep-equal-in-any-order](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/deep-equal-in-any-order/) plugin.

> Chai plugin to match objects and arrays deep equality with arrays (including nested ones) being in any order.

> It works in a similar way as `deep.equal` but it doesn’t check the order of the arrays (at any level of nested objects and arrays). The array elements can be any JS entity (boolean, null, number, string, object, array…).

E.g.

```js
const deepEqualInAnyOrder = require('deep-equal-in-any-order');
const chai = require('chai');

chai.use(deepEqualInAnyOrder);

const { expect } = chai;

describe('', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const actualResult = [
      {
        start: '30',
        end: '50',
        locations: ['loc1', 'loc2'],
      },
      {
        start: '20',
        end: '40',
        locations: ['loc3', 'loc4'],
      },
    ];

    const expectedResult = [
      {
        start: '20',
        end: '40',
        locations: ['loc4', 'loc3'],
      },
      {
        start: '30',
        end: '50',
        locations: ['loc2', 'loc1'],
      },
    ];

    expect(actualResult).to.deep.equalInAnyOrder(expectedResult);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  59308311
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (23ms)
```